# Collapsable sidebar to minimize sidenav for devices whose width > 768px

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am working on collapsable sidebar for my site and I found this really awesome template here

http://www.bootply.com/88026#

Here sidebar collapses when the width < 768px and we can toggle back the sibebar using the toggle button. This is works fine for mobile devices.

I want the users to be able to minimize the sidebar even on devices whose width > 768px.

Currently sidebar is collapsed using jquery

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
 $('[data-toggle=offcanvas]').click(function() {
 $('.row-offcanvas').toggleClass('active');
 });
 });
```

Here is a working example http://jsfiddle.net/cwzcuw67/

Any kind of pointers is appreciated

Comment: This may help you http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/simple-sidebar/

Comment: Please find the answer below and mark it as accepted if it has solved your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed it by adding an event listener to the red button.

```
$('.navbar-toggle') .click(function(){
  $('#sidebar').toggle();  // show/hide the sidebar
  $(this).find('i').toggleClass('fa-angle-right').toggleClass('fa-angle-left'); // toggle the angles in the red button
});
```

[Updated jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rdesai/cwzcuw67/3/)